# User folders on file server in WIndows Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, group-policy

We have a problem with users saving files to the local computer. I'm trying to implement some group policy to limit this. Whats the best way to give users a default folder on the server? Folder Redirection Group Policy, Home Directory in AD? Any other ways?

Comment: "Folder Redirection Group Policy, Home Directory in AD?": yes. and use both (i.e. setup 'Z' drive as home folder, then redirect MyDocuments to the Z drive. Then use the built-in 'offline' feature to sync the Z drive to the local machine. Done :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Folder Redirection.

Then just ACL the local drive.